# Redis - Sort ID's based on Names in another Set

Tags: redis

I am using multiple redis sets, hashes and Sorted sets for my use-case.
Suppose I am having a HASH set which stores ID and its corresponding object. (Project ID and its Content)
I have sets which contain list of ID's (List of ProjectIDs)
I have sorted sets which will sortBy DateTime fields and other Integer scores.
(Sort by DeadLine, Created etc and also by Project Name).
I also created a Sorted Set as my use-case needs Sort By Name (say Project Name). I created Project Name Sorted Set (ProjectName:ID as value and 0 as score).
So my requirement is that I need to sort my set (which contain ID's) based on Project Name in DESC or ASC.

How to achieve this??

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation about [`SORT`](https://redis.io/commands/sort) - it should be something like `SORT nameofzset BY nosort GET nameofhash->*`. Even better, learn how to write Lua scripts and execute them with [`EVAL`](https://redis.io/commands/eval).

Comment: I tried this the below way. SORT ZSET(List of IDs) BY HASHSET ->ProjectName. But did not work... as I want to sort list of ProjectIDs based on their names....